# Page content signature with HTTPS / TSL / SSL

Tags: ssl, curl, https, signature

I want the ability to prove to a third party (not myself) that I received some given content from a given https server, or in other words, have a signature of that content that can be verified against the public key of the SSL certificate of a website.

According to [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10520_.htm), it seems that a signature of the digest of the data is being sent and I am hoping that this is happening every time a page is loaded.  If that is right, how/where can I see/extract that signature? (e.g. using curl, whatever command line, tool...)

If my last assumption is inaccurate, is there a way that I can produce the proof described above?  And if so, how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

TLS uses data integrity control mechanism, but as the name suggests (TLS = Transport Layer Security), TLS is about protecting the data channel, not about "signing the data". TLS guarantees (or attempts to) that what has been sent via the protected channel remains unchanged in transit and it has not been altered by the third party. So you don't need to manually check any signatures besides the validation procedure performed by the TLS client on your behalf. If you trust your TLS client, then you trust the connection. You can perform additional checks of the certificate sent by the server, but you can't check the "signature of the digest of the data".

It's possible to craft a server which will calculate the signature of the data and put the signature to the response headers, but out of the box I didn't see any server doing this (or any client verifying such signatures).

Comment: I want to prove a third party (not myself) that the data come from a given website. (post edited)  What is the data integrity control mechanism?  (When does it happen? How/where can I see the result?)  According to the link, that very mechanism would be to calculate the digest of the message (I assume data) and sign it.

Comment: @andrew56 Please read the basics of TLS and you will understand what I have described. We have an introductory article on SSL/TLS here: https://www.eldos.com/security/articles/1948.php

Comment: I think I understood and understand what you said, yet that doesn't answer my question.  The handshake uses the certificate and tells ME that I am communicating with the key older.  Then I can trust that the data encrypted with that key is protected against thief and modifications.  However, it doesn't provide any assurance to anyone else that any data was send or encrypted by the server because I can myself encrypt any (modified) data with the key that is negotiated during handshake.

Comment: The Digital Signature discussed at the link I provided seem to be a probable solution to my problem, but I can't find where what is described actually happen.  What do you think I am missing or misunderstand?

Comment: @andrew56 yes, you can't prove anything to third-party with TLS. That is why I mentioned a separate signature being included to HTTP response headers - this is the only mechanism which you can implement (in code, as I don't think that HTTP servers support it out of the box) in order to prove anything to anyone.